# consume restful API from another port

Tags: rest, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I recently managed to create a restful API with DRF that is accessible through this http://192.168.33.10:8002/scenarios/. And I'm creating a ReactJS application which is accessible through this http://192.168.33.10:8001.

So basically my question is can I access my API from the second link while the port 8002 from the first link is closed?

Comment: What do you mean "the first link is closed" ?

Comment: i mean the port 8002 from the first link is closed

Answer (score 0):

You have to think as of both the ReactJS application and the RESTful API as two different applications, they'd live on two different addresses. You'd reach the API from React via the link that you provided (or if it is different in prod, via the new address)

Remember that the origin of the React application does not matter, the DRF REST API (server)  address is the same regardless of where the React application (client) resides.

Comment: So I do not need to activate the port of the DRF to be able to access the API ?